# DISKPART.EXE - Clean wrong disk

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover data from re-partitioned hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/230027/how-to-recover-data-from-re-partitioned-hard-drive)

I made a terrible mistake.

1. DISKPART.EXE
2. select *WrongHarddisk*
3. Clean

What is the best way to recover my data or restore the disk?

I found a program from [easeus](http://www.easeus.com/landing/datarecoverywizard.htm), but it is only free for 1 GB. Are there also other solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Great utility to recover your partition table and partitions.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but if you "cleaned" the disk/partition, it has been overwritten and is gone forever. No
program in the world can bring it back.

Comment: clean without "all" only zeroes the partition table, not the data itself. See "clean" on [Microsoft's diskpart description](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415/en-us).